# Задача с массивом JS

Tags: javascript

// Дан массив числами, например: [10, 20, 30, 50, 235, 3000]. 
// Выведите на экран только те числа из массива, которые начинаются на цифру 1, 2 или 5.
Мое решение:

```
for (i in arr) {
 let chr = Math.abs(arr[i]).toString()[0];
 if (chr === '1' || chr === '2' || chr === '5') { console.log(arr[i]); }
};
```

Вопрос:
Есть ли возможность решить задание с помощью методов перебора массива forEach или filter?

Comment: меняете `for` на `forEach`. В чем трудность?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const chrs = ['1', '2', '5'],
  result = [10, 20, 30, 50, 235, 3000].filter(e => chrs.includes(e.toString()[0]))

console.log(result)
```

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const chrs = ['1', '2', '5'],
  arr = [10, 20, 30, 50, 235, 3000]
let result = []

arr.forEach(e => chrs.includes(e.toString()[0]) ? result.push(e) : undefined)

console.log(result)
```

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const chrs = ['1', '2', '5'],
  result = [10, 20, 30, 50, 235, 3000].reduce((a, v) => {
    chrs.includes(v.toString()[0]) ? a.push(v) : undefined
    return a
  }, [])

console.log(result)
```